# Adjust PDF canvas maximum page size

Tags: shell, pdf, command-line-interface, ghostscript, pdftk

I have a PDF document in which all page sizes are different. I want to adjust each page size (aka the canvas) to the maximum width and the maximum height found in the document, and then center it.

I have got used to [pdftk](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pdftk) and [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/), but I may consider some other FOSS tool if it is better.

How to do that? Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made my share of pdfjam scripting, so I figured I'd give this a try.

I got a script working with `pdfinfo` and `pdfjam` (warning: this is based on pdflatex which is a big package, several hundred MBs):

```
#!/bin/bash

pdf=$1

nb_pages=$(pdfinfo "$pdf" | grep ^Pages: | cut -f2 -d:)
echo "Found $nb_pages pages in document"

# Get page sizes as string of width:height values in points (ie "2380:3368 3368:2380 1684:2380 ...")
page_sizes=$(seq $nb_pages | while read p; do pdfinfo -f $p -l $p "$pdf" | grep -e '^Page.* size:' | awk '{print $4,$6}'; done)
echo "Page sizes: $page_sizes"

max_width=$(echo $page_sizes | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -f 1 -d: | sort -n | tail -n 1)
echo "Max width: $max_width"

max_height=$(echo $page_sizes | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -f 2 -d: | sort -n | tail -n 1)
echo "Max height: $max_height"

# Run pdfjam on source pdf and set page size, it will center each page
set -x
pdfjam --suffix fixed "$pdf" --papersize "{${max_width}pt,${max_height}pt}"
```

It works (I tried it on "output.pdf" found on [this page](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PageSizes-sample.ashx)), but (at least on my system) I discovered there are limits to what you can pass to `--papersize` argument. If the pdfjam step fails for you, you can try a reduced size (keeping ratio) chosen manually and retry the command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this!

Comment: Hello, it seems this was "unaccepted" today. Is there any issue with the suggested solution?

Comment: Sorry. I would have preferred a unique-command-line solution, but it appears there is not. Maybe we should contact the Ghostscript creators, for instance. In any way, I want to thank you for your solution.

Comment: Well, in some way, the last line is your single-command solution, if you know the dimensions in advance. All the rest is just to figure out the dimensions you want according to your own logic :) By the way, it's OK to "unaccept", it's just that it would deserve a short comment to explain what was wrong.